# How to represent an empty character class in Java regex

Tags: java, regex, character-class

I want to create a character class that doesn't match any character. For now, I have been representing the pattern like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a&&b]");
```

or even

```
Pattern p = Patterncompile("[^\\x{0}-\\x{10FFFF}]");
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Note: there is no need to provide an alternative solution (negative lookahead, etc) that doesn't involve a character class. I'm just interested in knowing if there is a "right" way to do it.

Update: I'm implementing a feature which prints to the user the simplified version of what he inputted in the first place. Since I am simplifying character classes, my current version would just print `[]` for an input such as `[a&&b]`. If we parse `[]` again, it will throw an error, which is not what I want. Hence, that's why I wanted to know if there is a proper way to do it that does not alter the user input by showing him things like `^$`

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression which doesn't match anything? Surely you just need not to apply the regular expression? Or just `str.isEmpty()`?

Comment: I updated my question... I don't really get why the downvotes

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough that does not make much sense, you may use [*character class subtraction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) feature inside a character class to actually define a char and subtract it - then this class will not be able to match anything.

Example:

```
[a&&[^a]]
```

Since the character class should only match `a`, and the `a` is substracted, this pattern will not match anything.

Answer (score -2):

What you have made there are not **character classes**, they are regular expressions. If you want to match empty input ("doesn't match any character" in your words), use `^$`.